# How to set the html title when return image file in springboot?

Tags: spring-boot

I'm using springboot to return a image file. The image showed but the title is the RequestMapping value. How can I change the title.

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/press", produces = MediaType.IMAGE_JPEG_VALUE)
public ResponseEntity<Object> press(HttpServletRequest request) {
    InputStream in = servletContext.getResourceAsStream("/images/no_image.jpg");

    final HttpHeaders headers = new HttpHeaders();
    headers.setContentType(MediaType.IMAGE_PNG);

    return new ResponseEntity<byte[]>(IOUtils.toByteArray(in), headers, HttpStatus.CREATED);
}
```

The result is :
[image]

Comment: You cannot, you are only returning a `byte[]` of the image content. Specify the alt text on the `img` tag in the html you are creating.